# NoAvailableHostsException cassandra insert

Tags: playframework, cassandra, astyanax

I'm facing an issue with writing data into cassandra.

When using ConnectionPoolType.BAG we observed :

```
NoAvailableHostsException("No hosts to borrow from") exception being thrown.
Caused by: com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.NoAvailableHostsException:       
NoAvailableHostsException: [host=None(0.0.0.0):0, latency=0(0), attempts=1]No hosts to borrow from
at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.BagOfConnectionsConnectionPoolImpl.borrowConnection(BagOfConnectionsConnectionPoolImpl.java:93) ~[astyanax-1.56.24-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.BagOfConnectionsConnectionPoolImpl.access$000(BagOfConnectionsConnectionPoolImpl.java:31) ~[astyanax-1.56.24-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.BagOfConnectionsConnectionPoolImpl$BagExecuteWithFailover.borrowConnection(BagOfConnectionsConnectionPoolImpl.java:158) ~[astyanax-1.56.24-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.tryOperation(AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.java:67) ~[astyanax-1.56.24-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.executeWithFailover(AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.java:253) ~[astyanax-1.56.24-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl$6$3.execute(ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl.java:739) ~[astyanax-1.56.24-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
```

Also,  we  tried using ConnectionPoolType.ROUND_ROBIN but again we observed ConnectionTimeOut error.

### Would like to know if our configurations looks fine ?

Client configuration. We are using Astyanax java client.

```
        context = new AstyanaxContext.Builder()
                .forCluster("clustername")
                .forKeyspace("keyspace")
                .withAstyanaxConfiguration(new AstyanaxConfigurationImpl()
                        .setDiscoveryType(NodeDiscoveryType.NONE)
                        .setCqlVersion("3.0.0")
                        .setConnectionPoolType(ConnectionPoolType.BAG) // We also tried ConnectionPoolType.ROUND_ROBIN
                )
                .withConnectionPoolConfiguration(
                        new ConnectionPoolConfigurationImpl("poolname")
                                .setPort(9160)
                                .setMaxConnsPerHost(20)
                                .setInitConnsPerHost(10)
                                .setSeeds("host1:9160,host2:9160,host3:9160")
                                .setMaxTimeoutWhenExhausted(11000) // Default : 2000
                                .setConnectTimeout(10000) // Default : 2000
                )
                .withConnectionPoolMonitor(new Slf4jConnectionPoolMonitorImpl())
                .buildKeyspace(ThriftFamilyFactory.getInstance());context.start();
```

Update :

I'm facing an issue connecting to cassandra cluster from play framework. We are using astyanax java client to connect to the cluster.

When we start the play application using "play start" everything seems to be working fine  but when we create a dist using "play dist" command and start the service it throws the following exception.

What could be the difference between play dist and play start ?

Update 2 :
I'm testing on my machine, single instance of cassandra. I created the keyspace with "Simple Stragety" as the strategy.

Cassandra on my box : ReleaseVersion: 1.1.7. It also failed for version 1.1.6.

Running nodetool -h localhost  gave the following output.

Address         DC          Rack        Status State   Load            Effective-Ownership Token
127.0.0.1       datacenter1 rack1       Up     Normal  130.44 KB       100.00%             129209944818829357072522096381370300409

---

**CLOSING THE THREAD**
My problem was because of some conflicting thrift libraries. I had added dependencies for hive and also for cassandra and probably there was some mismatch.

THanks for the help.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you paste the ring information? Which strategy you are using while defining the keyspace? Also information about your Cassandra version

Comment: What do you get when you run `nodetool -h host1 ring`?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem trying to TRUNCATE a table (astyanax.version=1.0.6).
Truncation is a long operation because first of all Cassandra does a *sync*, that is, flushes all data from memory. It is a lot of data, so a read timeout happens.
One workaround to this problem is to first call `cassandraClient.send_truncate()` and then repeatedly `try{cassandraClient.recv_truncate();}`.
But if the timeout exception *is* thrown, we still get a "NoAvailableHostsException ... No hosts to borrow from". The reason for that exception is that deep inside thrift the connection is closed by submitting an asynchronous job to some executor. The remedy is to increase the time between retries (1000 ms is too small, 5000 works for me).